# grouped tableview showing the same row values for different sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a grouped tableview. i have 3 sections in that and trying to display different rows for all the sections using 1 array. but it is showing the same cell text for all the sections. here is the delegate methods which i implemented.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
mSectionArray =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc", @"def",@"ghi", nil] ;
return [mSectionArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   {


if(section == 0) {
    mContentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"hello1", nil];


}
if(section == 1) {
    mContentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two",@"three",@"four",@"five", nil];
    NSLog(@"section 1 %@",mContentArray);


}if (section == 2){
    mContentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc", nil];
}
return [mContentArray count];

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSString *sectionHeader = nil;

if(section == 0) {
    sectionHeader = @"abc";
}
if(section == 1) {
    sectionHeader = @"def";
}
if (section == 2) {
    sectionHeader = @"ghi";
}

return sectionHeader;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if(!cell){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [mContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
return cell;
}
```

it is showing "one" "two" "three" etc in all sections but i want different values for different sections. please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: Side note - please learn about `if-else` statements.

Comment: @Newbee check my updated answer. It resolved crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array should be like that:

```
intialize in viewDidLoad

  mContentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  NSArray * araray1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hello",@"hello1", nil];
  NSArray * araray2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two",@"three",@"four",@"five", nil];

  NSArray * araray3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"abc", nil];

  [mContentArray addObject:araray1];
  [mContentArray addObject:araray2];
  [mContentArray addObject:araray3];



  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 

    {
       return [mContentArray count];
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {           

         return [[mContentArray objectAtIndex:section]count];

   }
```

while retrieving

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[mContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Use modern syntax - `cell.textLabel.text = mContentArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];`.

Comment: is there any advantage of using this modern syntax ? If yes please explain

Comment: Creating the arrays is easier and less error prone too - `NSArray *array3 = @[ @"abc" ];`.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre i tried it but its crashing on the below code "    return [[mContentArray objectAtIndex:section]count];
"

Comment: Sorry for that, See my updated code in view didload methods. Now It will work.

Comment: @Newbee arrayWithObjects will create array of object inside of main Array. And initWithObjects simply create objects in your array.